# Suppress the error message "Web Part Error: Access Denied..." in Sharepoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, sharepoint-2013

I need advise, I'd been reading a lot of articles but to no avail.

Basically I have a TEAM site.

In my team site, I have various "out-of-box-applications". e.g calendar, doclibraries, etc...

On top site level, I added permissions to certain groups & visitors.
on app-level, example, "Calendar" - I took out "visitor".

- The reason I did this is because this app is private to the team... whereas the rest can be viewed by visitors.

However, if visitor tried to access the site, he/she will hit the message "Web Part Error: Access Denied. You do not have...... Correlation ID: XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZ-1234" on the calendar web part.

The million dollar question is: 
Is there a way to change the text (customize it, perhaps) or suppress it?
I'd been reading about 'Target Audience' but I still can't get the hang of it. I will however update if I manage to resolve this..

Thanks in advance for those with suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out after constant reading and trial/error.
Yes the solution is use "Target Audience" function.

Basically, I have 3 AD Groups:

```
    1. ADGroupApprover
    2. ADGroupContributor
    3. ADGroupDesigner
```

On Sharepoint, top level setting
*Go to Users & Permissions >> People and Groups*

Create a New SP Sgroup and explicitly add the AD Groups/Users.

On webpart, add now the "Target Audiene", it should populate now since the SP group is created.

> Downside: Adding the users "explicitly" will do the trick... but
>   somehow or what, the AD groups is not behaving as expected.

I'm still reading profile synchronization and etc.... so yep. will update the post again once I got an answer.

**UPDATE - Synching Active Directory to your SharePoint (profile synchronization):**

*Go to **Central Administration** >> Application Management >> Manage service applications >> User Profile Service Application.*

On Synchronization section:
(1) Configure Synchronizations Connections - create connection to your FQDN.. Use your farm account. Populate containers correctly.

- Connection Name: your preference
- Type: ADI
- FQDN: e.g contoso.com
- Auth prov type: Win Authen
- Auth prv instance: blank
- AcctName/Pwd: Farm account with admin rights
- Port: 389
- Unchecked (Use SSL, filter out)
- Filter in LDAP...: blank
- Populate Containers: based on your preference.

> Note: Above is my case, you can change this deliberately based on your
>   requirements.

(2) Configure Synchronizations Settings - on 'Synchronization Options', select "Use Sharepoint Active Directory Import".

(3) Start Profile Synchronization

After the profile is synchronized, you can now go back to the web part, the 'distribution/security group' should now be synched and populated with your Active Directory.

Hope this is helpful and clear. I tried to make it detailed as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can specify SharePoint Audience and assign your certain groups to this audience, then set the page or the list to be available for those Audience.

Go  to site administration -> People -> Mange Audience

I'm not sure but you can try

Comment: Hi, I will be vague... but I am really noob on this.. this is the first I design & manage sharepoint. As far as "Target Audience" is concern... Im kinda confused here.. Does it mean that I will open the "App permission to public" and assigned explicitly the audience? I am mixing "Target Audience" and "Permission Access"... Would be nice if you can explain it to me in a very high-level language. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, exactly. First make sure that you have user profile synchronization service run. For office 365 those are run automatically but for SP 2010 and 2013 you have to make sure those are run. If not, Target Audience field may not appear. And regarding the use of target audience, create a group for those who have the app permission, set them as your target audience (you can add multiple entities on target audience field). With this you can restrict permission to entities you need.For AD users to be available you have to make sure synchronization to be maintained between them.

Hope this helps.